# Develop a shiny app login locally

Tags: r, authentication, shiny

I want to develop a shiny app with login, which later should be hosted on `Shinyapps.io` (STANDARD). 
How can I develope/debug the app locally without having Shiny Server Pro or uploading the app to `Shinyapps.io` every time.

Running the code displayed [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/authentication-and-database.html).

I of course get the following message:

> ERROR: This application is designed to be run in Shiny Server Pro and to require authentication.

Comment: One possibility is to use the  [Download Free 45-Day Evaluation](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny-server-pro/evaluation/)

Comment: One can simply use the [Authentication and Authorization Model](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shinyapps-io-authentication-authorization/). Nothing needs to be developed. ..